# Are there any fast approximations to generalized linear mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, approximation, parallel-computing

Are there any recommended methods or approximations that would help speed up the estimation of fixed effects components of a generalized linear mixed effects model?

Specifically, my dataset includes individuals performing a task potentially many times, and the task contains a leveling structure such that any individual who reaches a very high level is likely to have had superior ability to begin with. 
Without a random effect per individual, this correlation will distort my estimates.

I need to obtain the fixed effects in order predict the performance of a new individual at different levels. I don't actually care about the random effects estimates themselves, I just need to include them in order to remove this distortion.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Just a thought: Treat all random effects as fixed effect. Yeah, sure it suboptimal but especially in large samples (I assume you have a large sample as speed is the main issue) your estimates for $\beta$ will not be horribly off.

Comment: Good starting values (e.g. from estimating a fixed effects model) and a good & fast implementation (e.g. for some problems PROC MIXED in SAS seemed to be a lot better than other implementations for years, not sure whether this is still the case).

Comment: @user11852 Actually, treating the random effects (1 per individual) as a fixed effect can be even slower than using the mixed model given the large number of levels that need to be fit.